# Is it safe to use .RequireRole() without .RequireAuthenticatedUser() in ASP.NET Core authorization policies?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

There are some policies defines in *Startup.cs* like:

```cs
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("UsersEdit", policy => policy
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .RequireRole("Admin"));
});
```

Is it safe to rewrote this code to:

```cs
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("UsersEdit", policy => policy.RequireRole("Admin"));
});
```

I guess that unauthorized user can't have any roles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we check the source code for the authorization requirement that gets added by `RequireAuthenticatedUser` at https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/c376e833e46497fbec4bd7b39632f8c8e13360b2/src/Security/Authorization/Core/src/DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement.cs:

```
var user = context.User;
var userIsAnonymous =
    user?.Identity == null ||
    !user.Identities.Any(i => i.IsAuthenticated);
    if (!userIsAnonymous)
    {
        context.Succeed(requirement);
    }
```

It adds a check that user must have an identity, and that one of them must say the user is authenticated.

`IsAuthenticated` says the following in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsidentity.isauthenticated?view=netframework-4.8#System_Security_Claims_ClaimsIdentity_IsAuthenticated):

> true if the AuthenticationType property is not null or an empty string.

So in theory a user could have a role by having an identity that has no authentication type.
But in practice, that should not happen.
Any reasonable authentication handler would not leave AuthenticationType empty, since then `IsAuthenticated` would return `false`.