# Do we need to include RequireAuthenticatedUser when building a policy that requires claims?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, model-view-controller, authorization

When you create a custom policy in ASP.NET Core like this:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("MyCustomPolicy",
            policyBuilder => policyBuilder.RequireClaim("SomeClaim"));
    });
```

What is the difference from defining it as above, versus defining it the following way:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("MyCustomPolicy",
            policyBuilder => policyBuilder.RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                             .RequireClaim("SomeClaim"));
    });
```

I mean, is it even possible to have a claim, without being authenticated? If yes - how does it work? An example demonstrating that behavior would be great!

**EDIT:** [This](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c376e833e46497fbec4bd7b39632f8c8e13360b2/src/Security/Authorization/Core/src/ClaimsAuthorizationRequirement.cs) is the source code of the requirement behind calling `RequireClaim`, and [here's](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c376e833e46497fbec4bd7b39632f8c8e13360b2/src/Security/Authorization/Core/src/DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement.cs) the one for `RequireAuthenticatedUser`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58948479/is-it-safe-to-use-requirerole-without-requireauthenticateduser-in-asp-net

Answer (score 2):

From the doc about [AuthorizationPolicyBuilder.RequireAuthenticatedUser method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.authorizationpolicybuilder.requireauthenticateduser?view=aspnetcore-3.1), we can find:

```
Adds a DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement to the current instance
```

And the following example could help know how it works.

*Add a custom claim*

```
app.UseAuthentication();

app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    //add a claim to this claims identity
    context.User.Identities.FirstOrDefault().AddClaim(new Claim("SomeClaim", "testval"));

    await next.Invoke();
});

app.UseAuthorization();
```

*If not call `.RequireAuthenticatedUser` method*

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("MyCustomPolicy",
        policyBuilder => policyBuilder.RequireClaim("SomeClaim"));

});
```

We can find anonymous user can also pass claims check and access the resource, like below.

[image]

Comment: In other words: you can add claims to an anonymous user in your application - no problem. E.g. "UserHasAcceptedCookies" could be a claim that allows the user access to certain parts of your website even though they're not authenticated.